# Deleting SQL record using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I am a beginner in PHP and SQL. I have been trying to delete rows in SQL table using the following code but it doesn't work. Please help.

```
<?php
/* 
 DELETE.PHP
 Deletes a specific entry from the 'db' table
*/

 // connect to the database
 include('connect-db.php');

 // check if the 'id' variable is set in URL, and check that it is valid

 // get id value
 $id = $_GET['id'];

 // delete the entry
 $result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM db WHERE 'Report No.'= '$id'")
 or die(mysql_error()); 

 // redirect back to the view page
 header("Location: view.php");

 // if id isn't set, or isn't valid, redirect back to view page
 {
 header("Location: view.php");
 }

?>
```

Comment: db is your table name? and  Report No.?? what is this, here you need to give your your table field name.

Comment: Wrap off quotes form column name instead use backtick

Comment: echo the delete query and run over phpmyadmin SQL tab. is it executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply backticks(`) around table field name "Report No." (its not standard way to define a table field name)

Try this

```
$result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM db WHERE `Report No.`= '$id'");
```

Answer (score -1):

Fix your query by removing single quote of name table:

```
$result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM db WHERE `Report No.`= '$id'");
```

Make sure that you type right for **Report No.** column name. Actually for naming **Report No.** is not recommended.

Comment: Removing single quotes cause error as whitespace is not accepted. However replacing single quote by backticks helped. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: What database you use? Its because your table name contain space. So you have to add ` sign for Report No. I guess for simple name without space it can work.